# How to serialize/deserialize a protobuf message that uses 'oneof' with ScalaPB?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I'm using ScalaPB to compile my Scala case classes for serializing my protobuf messages.

I have a `.proto` file with the following messages:

```
message WrapperMessage {
    oneof msg {
        Login login = 1;
        Register register = 2;
    }
}

message Login {
    required string email = 1;
    required string password = 2;
}

message Register {
    required string email = 1;
    required string password = 2;
    optional string firstName = 3;
    optional string lastName = 4;
}
```

How do I create my `WrapperMessage` knowing that I want to put a `Login` message inside the `msg`?

```
  val login = Login(email = "test@example.com", password = "testpass")
  val wrapperMessage = WrapperMessage(???)
  val wrapperMessageBytes = wrapperMessage.toByteArray
```

Let's say now that I am receiving a `WrapperMessage` over the wire; how do I deserialize the message using ScalaPB case class methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ScalaPB has documentation which clearly provides examples for the questions I am asking. In this answer I tailor the examples provided on ScalaPB towards my question.

To initialize a message with `oneof`:

```
val login = Login(email = "test@example.com", password = "testpass")
val wrapperMessage = WrapperMessage().withLogin(login)
```

To match against a message's `oneof` field:

```
wrapperMessage.msg match {
  case Msg.Login(l) =>  // handle l
  case Msg.Register(r) =>  // handle r
  case Msg.Empty =>  // handle exceptional case...
}
```

Comment: I've used ScalaPB before but not the `oneof` feature. It's good to see that they've translated the Java API to more idiomatic Scala patterns where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to initialize `WrapperMessage` with an empty constructor and call `.set_login(login)`

You would deserialize to `WrapperMessage` and pattern match on `message.WhichOneof` which returns either "login" or "register". Then you would call the accessor on that specific message (ie. `message.login`).

Comment: I was able to initialize `WrapperMessage` succesfully using your advice. In Scala I used `WrapperMessage().setLogin(login)`. I believe `WhichOneof` is available only in the Python API. I can only use methods that are in the Java API using ScalaPB. Is there an elegant solution here?

Comment: Oh, the Java API has `getOneofNameCase` which returns an enum to indicated which field is set. The enum should be defined in your protobuf scala definition, assuming that ScalaPB supports it.

Comment: I'm sure there is a solution that works like this, but found my answer simply looking towards ScalaPB's [documentation](https://trueaccord.github.io/ScalaPB/generated-code.html)...